Por qué la respuesta de la petición AJAX no aparece en la consola pero si en el depurador del navegador
Estoy realizando una petición AJAX a una hoja de sheets que entrega un contenido descargado y que la idea principal es leer ese contenido de la hoja. todo funciona bien en paginas de prueba de codigo online quitando jsonp porque sino, no funciona. pero estoy probando ahora el codigo de forma local en mi computador añadiendo jsonp porque sino me da error 200 pero primero en la consola muestra: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined... seguido de los errores en la funcion error de AJAX pero si me voy al depurador aparece todo el contenido obtenido, es decir que en vez de mostrarlo en la consola lo muestra en el depurador. qué hago?


$.ajax({
  url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/-ID-/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=0",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: (json) => {
    console.log(json);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
  },
});





Diria que tienes que gestionar esa respuesta pues te ponen cosas que sobran.  Usa replacepara ello. Algo asi como replace("/*O_o*/", "").replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse(", "").slice(0, -2)); para borrar todo eso que sobra y a ver si así lo ves bien.

por que funcionan de forma distinta, la consola imprimira solo lo que le dices que imprima, el depurador muestra un backtrace de la ejecucion incluyendo la linea de codigo con error ...

adicional en consola en donde dice saber mas ... te muestra el objeto completo del evento.

@FranciscoNuñezIALover no, simplemente me lleva a una página de mozilla sobre la descripción del error y dice que la variable no está definida.

@masterguru no me funciona, ya que el mensaje lo muestra al realizar la petición, ni siquiera deja manejar respuesta

bueno segun lo que se ve falta codigo ... eso de google.visualization no se de donde sale ... no se ve en el codigo que esta mostrando...

No me es posible reproducir tu escenario, me da un error 404 al intentarlo. Mírate esta página a ver si sacas algo sobre tu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765773/converting-google-visualization-query-result-into-javascript-array

El código 200 no es un error, en realidad es un estatus de "exito" en la petición, incluso se muestra el objeto, pero estas obteniendo un error "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" lo cual indica el problema. Dime como cargas la API, agrega más código?

JSONP retorna un script que es evaluado y ejecutado en tu aplicación, es algo bastante peligroso si desconoces el origen de aquel script
En tu caso retorna la llamada a una función google.visualization.Query.setResponse(UnObjeto). Supongo que esa función debe estar en alguna libreria de google, tú al no contar con dicha función te arroja el error Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
Para solucionarlo, basta con crear una función que se llame igual


//Creamos una función de igual nombre a "google.visualization.Query.setResponse"
const google = {
   visualization:{
      Query: {
        setResponse: (data) =>{
           //aqui hago algo con los datos
           console.log(data);
        }
      }
   }
};

$.ajax({
  url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p707iG4QW9klG-FoSqoBET2gSgFmrGPjkwJxFUrWoHo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=0",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Como indica @Marcos en su comentario, puedes cambiar el nombre de la función agregándolo como parámetro en la URL.
Para esto en el parámetro tqx debes agregar: responseHandler:nombre_de_la_función. Como además el parametro tqx ya tiene el campo out, para agregar otro debes concatenarlo junto con un ; (punto y coma)
?tqx=out:json;responseHandler:nombre_de_la_función



//Creamos una función de igual nombre a "google.visualization.Query.setResponse"
function procesar(data){
  console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p707iG4QW9klG-FoSqoBET2gSgFmrGPjkwJxFUrWoHo/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json;responseHandler:procesar&tq&gid=0",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Según la documentación de Charts si no se indica el nombre de la función de control Javascript mediante el parámetro responseHandler, el valor predeterminado es google.visualization.Query.setResponse. Más info

Gracias @Yussef por la solución era lo que esperaba.

El problema es que estás usando Ajax cuando la API de Google Charts tiene todo lo que se necesita para que puedas acceder a la data sin necesidad de utilizar Ajax o Jquery.
./js/spreadsheetsWithCharts.js

google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGID);

function drawGID() {
    var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, H, O, Q, R, U LIMIT 5 OFFSET 8');

    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWJLkAwch5GXAt_7zOFDcg8Wm8Xv29_8PWuuW15qmAE/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    console.log(data)//<------ Aquí la data que necesitas. 
    chart.draw(data, { height: 400 });
  }

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spreadsheets With Charts</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/spreadsheetsWithCharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>

</html>


